# Slow QTreeWidgetItem.setBackground and QTreeWidgetItem.setForeground

Tags: qt

I'm developing an application that does data acquisition and plotting, with a target refresh rate of 60FPS.

I use a QTreeWidget with 4 columns to hold the signals information. Depending on each signal's current value, the associated QTreeWidgetItem needs to update the font color and background. This update is done only if the QTreeWidgetItem is visible.

There is a clear freeze when the updates occur (32 visible signals in the GIF), and I've determined that the freeze is caused by this code:

```
    if new_background_color is None:
        if self._background_color != self.background(0).color():
            self.setBackground(0, self._background_color)
            self.setBackground(1, self._background_color)
            self.setBackground(2, self._background_color)
            self.setBackground(3, self._background_color)
    else:
        if new_background_color != self.background(0).color():
            self.setBackground(0, new_background_color)
            self.setBackground(1, new_background_color)
            self.setBackground(2, new_background_color)
            self.setBackground(3, new_background_color)

    if new_font_color is None:
        if self.signal.color != self.foreground(0).color():
            self.setForeground(0, self.signal.color)
            self.setForeground(1, self.signal.color)
            self.setForeground(2, self.signal.color)
            self.setForeground(3, self.signal.color)
    else:
        if new_font_color != self.foreground(0).color():
            self.setForeground(0, new_font_color)
            self.setForeground(1, new_font_color)
            self.setForeground(2, new_font_color)
            self.setForeground(3, new_font_color)
```

[image]

For reference the plot is fluid when I disable the above code snippet

[image]

Why are those functions so expensive? Is there some faster alternative?

Comment: Is data acqusition itself running on Main (GUI) or separated thread?

Comment: The data acquisition is running in separate processes. There is a Python thread with runs a C code function that gathers the new samples from the other processes (data is exchanged using shared memory). If I disable the above code snippet then the values column text is still updated, and the plot runs fluently at 60FPS.

Comment: I've added a GIF with the code snippet disabled

Answer (score 0):

What actually happened was that the QTreeWidget.itemChanged signal was connected to a function that should have only handled the check state changes, but the foreground and background changes were also treated the same way, leading to wasted CPU cycles.